# How to replace set of repeating String pattern with specific character?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

**Sample Input**

```
00000000255255255255000000000255255000000000000002552552552552552552550000000000
```

I need to replace this string as follows using regx

**Sample Output**

```
00000000000,0000000000000000,000000000000000,0000000000
```

suppose the code is like this

```
s="00000000255255255255000000000255255000000000000002552552552552552552550000000000";
s.replace("regularexpression",",");
```

Comment: You want to remove all non-zero digits?. Show us the sample output.

Comment: Do you want to `replace all` series of `one or more` digits which are not zeroes (are in range `1-9`) with `,`? If that is the case than why in your result there are more zeroes than at in your input?

Comment: @TheLostMind it's not that simple I guess, note that the number of zero was changed in output.

Comment: @Kent - Actually, I am not able to understand what the OP wants.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am glad to know that I am not the only one. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing your sample output was mistaken...

If you would like to replace all contiguous groups of non-zero digits in a string with a comma, try this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[1-9]+", ",");
```

If you are trying to replace all substrings that repeat "255" one or more times with a comma, try this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(255)+", ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to split on non-0 multiple digits, here is a solution:

```
String input = "00000000255255255255000000000255255000000000000002552552552552552552550000000000";
//                 | String representation of the split array
//                 |                     | splitting...
//                 |                     |      |... on a character class...
//                 |                     |      || ...for any digit non-0
//                 |                     |      ||   | in 1+ sequential instances
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("[1-9]+")));
```

**Output**

```
[00000000, 000000000, 00000000000000, 0000000000]
```

Comment: it doesn't match the output given by OP... `00000000000,0000000000000000,000000000000000,0000000000`

Comment: @Kent just noticed, fixing. thanks

Comment: I am curious if you can fix it.... I don't understand the requirement at all. :-D

Comment: @Kent actually I'm assuming the desired output has typos. Waiting for OP to clarify.